# Apache - Use a unique index.php with existing folders

Tags: apache

I want to redirect all the pages of my website (non existing files and folders) to a unique index.php. It's simple, this is my .htaccess into the root of my website:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php
ErrorDocument 400 /index.php?er=400
ErrorDocument 401 /index.php?er=401
ErrorDocument 403 /index.php?er=403
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?er=404
ErrorDocument 406 /index.php?er=406
ErrorDocument 408 /index.php?er=408
ErrorDocument 411 /index.php?er=411
ErrorDocument 500 /index.php?er=500
```

It works fine for non existing files and folders BUT I need to keep some real folders to store files and I get a 403 Forbiden error when I call "site.com/folder/"

For example if folderA doesn't exists, every call to "site.com/folderA/..." works and I have a 200 OK response for the folder, subfolders and files.
But if folderB exists, I get 404 for all non-existing files and 403 for non-existing subfolders instead of the redirection to my main index.php.

What solutions Do I have to keep thoses folders and redirect all non existing urls to my index ?

Thank you

Comment: Does folderB have its own .htaccess file?  Getting 404's for non-existing files inside there is not the behavior I would expect unless it has its own rewrite rules and is not inheriting the root's.

Comment: You are right, I had a htaccess in folderB. Without it all works well but I have a 403 if I call site.com/folderB/ probably because it is looking for an index.php and didn't find it so it refuses access to the folder

Comment: it is why I added a htaccess redirecting index.php to root /index.php but it makes other problems. How avoid 403 on "site.com/folderB/" ?

Comment: What should `/folderB/` do instead of a 403 due to a missing index? Should that go to `/index.php`?  Perhaps you could set `ErrorDocument 403 /index.php` (without `er=403`) inside `/folderB/.htaccess` to handle that, but remove all mod_rewrite stuff from `/folderB/.htaccess`.

Comment: @Michael, using `ErrorDocument 403` will still get you lots of entries in the error log for such requests – I’d therefor recommend to rather use `DirectoryIndex /index.php`

Comment: @CBroe Excellent point. Does that work? You can specify DirectoryIndex with a path? Very cool.

Comment: Yes, it works – I used it a couple of times for a custom directory listing script. Sure, could have gone for mod_rewrite in that situation as well – but why complicate things, right? (Using a relative path, such as `DirectoryIndex foo/index.php` would treat that as relative to the current directory that the index is created for, so that won’t be helpful in most situations – but a path with a leading slash is taken as relative to the domain root, same way as it would in HTML.)

Comment: wahou ! `DirectoryIndex /index.php` works perfectly ! THANKS ! In fact, the problem with 403 was that the environment variables didn't follow (empty $_POST and $_GET in PHP) and its bad for referencing ! The `folderB/.htaccess` using mod_rewrite makes problems but with DirectoryIndex it works nice !

Comment: @CBroe That is worth a real answer.

Comment: I'm agree with Michael, please @CBroe can you make an answer below, I will accept it as the solution, thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not only want all non-existing folders to be routed to your index.php (which your rewrite rules will achieve), but the existing ones as well, instead of getting a 403 for those, you can simply use the `DirectoryIndex` directive like this:

`DirectoryIndex /index.php`

`DirectoryIndex` does not only accept a file name, but a local URL as well – and the leading slash makes it relative to the domain root.

So for all your existing folders, your `index.php` located at the domain root will now be served as the index document.

---

This could of course be achieved by other means as well – but using mod_rewrite for this would involve more checks, and using `ErrorDocument 403` would still write an entry into the server’s error log for every existing folder you request.